# Connect over two collections using Mongo's $graphLookup

Tags: mongodb

I am familiar with using Mongo's `$graphLookup` with a single collection but cannot get it working with two collections that link to each other.

Example:

`systems`:

```
{ "_id": 0, "signatures": [ 10 ] }
{ "_id": 1, "signatures": [ 11, 12 ] }
{ "_id": 2, "signatures": [] }
{ "_id": 3, "signatures": [] }
```

`signatures`:

```
{ "_id": 10, "destination": 1 }
{ "_id": 11, "destination": 2 }
{ "_id": 12, "destination": 3 }
```

I.e., There is a one-to-many relation between systems and signatures with signatures linking back to exactly one system. I guess what I'm trying to do is essentially reducing the signature relation away.

What I'm looking to get:

```
{
  "_id": 0,
  "connections": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "connections": [
        { "_id": 2, "connections": [] },
        { "_id": 3, "connections": [] }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And the way I was approaching this:

```
systems.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: 0 } },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "systems",
      startWith: "$_id",
      connectFromField: "signatures.destination",
      connectToField: "_id",
      maxDepth: 5,
      as: "connections",
    },
  },
]);
```

The above yields just the original document as the sole connection:

```
{
  "_id": 0,
  "signatures": [ 10 ],
  "connections": [
    { "_id": 0, "signatures": [ 10 ] }
  ]
}
```

While searching for help, I could not find examples where the recursive search happens over two collections, only ones where the initial search is done on a different collection. That made my wonder if this is possible at all with `$graphLookup`?

EDIT: I probably should add that in my use `signature` contains additional fields which is the reason I have such a schema. I guess I could link systems directly to each other but, if possible, I would prefer to keep the current schema as it is quite nice to use in my application.